# rotate the widget for some degree

Tags: python, pyqt

I am a new to pyqt and need help with rotating the label. I am confused and cannot understand how to rotate the whole widget on a specific angle. Not the content of the widget, but the widget itself. I am searching for the solution but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 3):

A QWidget does not support rotation, but a workaround is to insert the widget into a QGraphicsProxyWidget and add it to a QGraphicsScene, and then rotate the QGraphicsProxyWidget that visually generates the same widget rotation effect.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Stack Overflow", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    graphicsview = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(graphicsview)
    graphicsview.setScene(scene)

    proxy = QtWidgets.QGraphicsProxyWidget()
    proxy.setWidget(label)
    proxy.setTransformOriginPoint(proxy.boundingRect().center())
    scene.addItem(proxy)

    slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(minimum=0, maximum=359, orientation=QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    slider.valueChanged.connect(proxy.setRotation)

    label_text = QtWidgets.QLabel(
        "{}°".format(slider.value()), alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
    )
    slider.valueChanged.connect(
        lambda value: label_text.setText("{}°".format(slider.value()))
    )

    slider.setValue(45)

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(graphicsview)
    lay.addWidget(slider)
    lay.addWidget(label_text)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As @eyllanesc correctly explains, there's no "widget rotation" support in Qt (as in most standard frameworks).

There are a couple of tricks on your hand, though.

### "Simple" label (not using a `QLabel`)

That's the "simple" solution. Since you're talking about a "label", that can be implemented using some math.

The biggest advantage in this approach is that the size hint is "simple", meaning that it's only based on the text contents (as in [`QFontMetrics.boundingRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-2)), and whenever the main font, text or alignment is changed, the size hint reflects them.
While it supports multi-line labels, the biggest problem about this approach comes in place if you need to use rich text, though; a [`QTextDocument`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) can be used instead of a standard string, but that would require a more complex implementation for size hint computing.

```
from math import radians, sin, cos
from random import randrange

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class AngledLabel(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    _alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop

    def __init__(self, text='', angle=0, parent=None):
        super(AngledLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._text = text
        self._angle = angle % 360
        # keep radians of the current angle *and* its opposite; we're using
        # rectangles to get the overall area of the text, and since they use
        # right angles, that opposite is angle + 90
        self._radians = radians(-angle)
        self._radiansOpposite = radians(-angle + 90)

    def alignment(self):
        return self._alignment

    def setAlignment(self, alignment):
        # text alignment might affect the text size!
        if alignment == self._alignment:
            return
        self._alignment = alignment
        self.setMinimumSize(self.sizeHint())

    def angle(self):
        return self._angle

    def setAngle(self, angle):
        # the angle clearly affects the overall size
        angle %= 360
        if angle == self._angle:
            return
        self._angle = angle
        # update the radians to improve optimization of sizeHint and paintEvent
        self._radians = radians(-angle)
        self._radiansOpposite = radians(-angle + 90)
        self.setMinimumSize(self.sizeHint())

    def text(self):
        return self._text

    def setText(self, text):
        if text == self._text:
            return
        self._text = text
        self.setMinimumSize(self.sizeHint())

    def sizeHint(self):
        # get the bounding rectangle of the text
        rect = self.fontMetrics().boundingRect(QtCore.QRect(), self._alignment, self._text)
        # use trigonometry to get the actual size of the rotated rectangle
        sinWidth = abs(sin(self._radians) * rect.width())
        cosWidth = abs(cos(self._radians) * rect.width())
        sinHeight = abs(sin(self._radiansOpposite) * rect.height())
        cosHeight = abs(cos(self._radiansOpposite) * rect.height())
        return QtCore.QSize(cosWidth + cosHeight, sinWidth + sinHeight)

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return self.sizeHint()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        textRect = self.fontMetrics().boundingRect(
            QtCore.QRect(), self._alignment, self._text)
        width = textRect.width()
        height = textRect.height()
        # we have to translate the painting rectangle, and that depends on which
        # "angle sector" the current angle is
        if self._angle <= 90:
            deltaX = 0
            deltaY = sin(self._radians) * width
        elif 90 < self._angle <= 180:
            deltaX = cos(self._radians) * width
            deltaY = sin(self._radians) * width + sin(self._radiansOpposite) * height
        elif 180 < self._angle <= 270:
            deltaX = cos(self._radians) * width + cos(self._radiansOpposite) * height
            deltaY = sin(self._radiansOpposite) * height
        else:
            deltaX = cos(self._radiansOpposite) * height
            deltaY = 0
        qp.translate(.5 - deltaX, .5 - deltaY)
        qp.rotate(-self._angle)
        qp.drawText(self.rect(), self._alignment, self._text)


class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.randomizeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Randomize!')
        layout.addWidget(self.randomizeButton, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.randomizeButton.clicked.connect(self.randomize)

        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Standard label'), 1, 0)
        text = 'Some text'
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(text), 1, 2)
        self.labels = []
        for row, angle in enumerate([randrange(360) for _ in range(8)], 2):
            angleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(u'{}°'.format(angle))
            angleLabel.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
            layout.addWidget(angleLabel, row, 0)
            label = AngledLabel(text, angle)
            layout.addWidget(label, row, 2)
            self.labels.append((angleLabel, label))

        separator = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        separator.setFrameShape(separator.VLine|separator.Sunken)
        layout.addWidget(separator, 1, 1, layout.rowCount() - 1, 1)

    def randomize(self):
        for angleLabel, label in self.labels:
            angle = randrange(360)
            angleLabel.setText(str(angle))
            label.setAngle(angle)
        self.adjustSize()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TestWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### `QGraphicsView` implementation

I would also like to expand the solution proposed by eyllanesc, as it is more modular and allows to use "any" widget; unfortunately, while his answer works as expected, I'm afraid that it's an answer that is just valid "for the sake of the argument".
From the graphical point of view, the obvious issues are the QGraphicsView visual hints (borders and background). But, since we're talking about widgets that might have to be inserted in a graphical interface, the size (and its hint[s]) require some care.
The main advantage of this approach is that *almost any type of widget* can be added to the interface, but due to the nature of per-widget size policy and QGraphicsView implementations, if the content of the "rotated" widget changes, perfect drawing will always be something hard to achieve.

```
from random import randrange
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class AngledObject(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    _angle = 0

    def __init__(self, angle=0, parent=None):
        super(AngledObject, self).__init__(parent)
        # to prevent the graphics view to draw its borders or background, set the
        # FrameShape property to 0 and a transparent background
        self.setFrameShape(0)
        self.setStyleSheet('background: transparent')
        self.setScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene())
        # ignore scroll bars!
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)

    def angle(self):
        return self._angle

    def setAngle(self, angle):
        angle %= 360
        if angle == self._angle:
            return
        self._angle = angle
        self._proxy.setTransform(QtGui.QTransform().rotate(-angle))
        self.adjustSize()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(AngledObject, self).resizeEvent(event)
        # ensure that the scene is fully visible after resizing
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.centerOn(self.sceneRect().center()))

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.scene().itemsBoundingRect().size().toSize()

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return self.sizeHint()


class AngledLabel(AngledObject):
    def __init__(self, text='', angle=0, parent=None):
        super(AngledLabel, self).__init__(angle, parent)
        self._label = QtWidgets.QLabel(text)
        self._proxy = self.scene().addWidget(self._label)
        self._label.setStyleSheet('background: transparent')
        self.setAngle(angle)
        self.alignment = self._label.alignment

    def setAlignment(self, alignment):
        # text alignment might affect the text size!
        if alignment == self._label.alignment():
            return
        self._label.setAlignment(alignment)
        self.setMinimumSize(self.sizeHint())

    def text(self):
        return self._label.text()

    def setText(self, text):
        if text == self._label.text():
            return
        self._label.setText(text)
        self.setMinimumSize(self.sizeHint())


class AngledButton(AngledObject):
    def __init__(self, text='', angle=0, parent=None):
        super(AngledButton, self).__init__(angle, parent)
        self._button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(text)
        self._proxy = self.scene().addWidget(self._button)
        self.setAngle(angle)


class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.randomizeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Randomize!')
        layout.addWidget(self.randomizeButton, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.randomizeButton.clicked.connect(self.randomize)

        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Standard label'), 1, 0)
        text = 'Some text'
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(text), 1, 2)
        self.labels = []
        for row, angle in enumerate([randrange(360) for _ in range(4)], 2):
            angleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(u'{}°'.format(angle))
            angleLabel.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
            layout.addWidget(angleLabel, row, 0)
            label = AngledLabel(text, angle)
            layout.addWidget(label, row, 2)
            self.labels.append((angleLabel, label))

        for row, angle in enumerate([randrange(360) for _ in range(4)], row + 1):
            angleLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(u'{}°'.format(angle))
            angleLabel.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
            layout.addWidget(angleLabel, row, 0)
            label = AngledButton('Button!', angle)
            layout.addWidget(label, row, 2)
            self.labels.append((angleLabel, label))

        separator = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        separator.setFrameShape(separator.VLine|separator.Sunken)
        layout.addWidget(separator, 1, 1, layout.rowCount() - 1, 1)

    def randomize(self):
        for angleLabel, label in self.labels:
            angle = randrange(360)
            angleLabel.setText(str(angle))
            label.setAngle(angle)
        self.adjustSize()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TestWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see, the "randomize" functions have very different results. While the second approach allows using more complex widgets, the first one better reacts to contents changes.